# OpenCart extension installer showing uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Tags: php, configuration, opencart2.x

I want to install SEOMATIC extension for SEO in opencart varsion 2.0.2.0 but when i tried to uplaod the zip file via extension installer showing this message.

[image]

And my php.ini config file is

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
;The next 3 lines
display_errors = 1;
error_reporting = E_ALL;
log_errors = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a problem with the post_max_size directory.

Set it to same as the upload_max_filesize

post_max_size = 999M

BUT I would not recommend this to be 999, Maximum 50M but it is up to you if you want to crash your server ;)

Comment: There could be a problem with the post_max_size switch (not directory)

Comment: It looks like this is not solving the issue for me with an extension of 2.4 MB, any other solution?

Comment: Are you use you are editing the correct php.ini file? Where are your php.ini file located and what OS is on the system?

Comment: I was editing the php.ini inside the opencart... I think I managed to sort it out by setting those in .htaccess

Comment: Use phpinfo() to see the currently loaded php.ini file and modify that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP, Wamp or MAMP, you will find the php.ini in following locations.

For XAMPP users

Windows:  `C:/xampp/php/php.ini`

macOS: `/private/etc/php.ini`

Linux: `/etc/php.ini`

Find this line in it `upload_max_filesize=2M` (line number 838)

default uploading file size is 2 megabytes in XAMPP, so change size you want,
(if your file size is 3 megabytes) 
change parameter

```
upload_max_filesize=4M
```

(Before save file stop your Apache server)